# Merge two DOM documents using XERCES

Tags: c++, xerces, xerces-c

I just need to append 1 xml sub-tree to another using xerces,

```
                DOMNode *tempNode;
                DOMElement *temp;
                DOMNode *paraNode;
                DOMNode *dest;

                XMLCh *xmlchElems = XMLString::transcode("lists");
                XMLCh *xmlchElem = XMLString::transcode("list1");

                DOMNodeList *mainElm1 = defDoc1->getElementsByTagName(xmlchElems);
                DOMNodeList *mainElm2 = defDoc2->getElementsByTagName(xmlchElems);

                DOMNodeList *defs1 = ((DOMElement*)(mainElm1->item(0)))->getElementsByTagName(xmlchElem);
                DOMNodeList *defs2 = ((DOMElement*)(mainElm2->item(0)))->getElementsByTagName(xmlchElem);

//
//   Merging starts here
//
                paraNode = mainElm2->item(0);
                tempNode = defs1->item(0);
                dest = defDoc1->importNode(tempNode, true);
                paraNode->appendChild(dest);
```

file1.xml

```
<file1>
<lists>
    <list1> </list1>
    <list2> </list2>
</lists>
</file1>
```

file2.xml

```
<file2>
<lists>
    <list1> </list1>
    <list2> </list2>
</lists>
</file2>
```

Please suggest the API's that should be used for this purpose.

Comment: Using Xerces you'll need to copy the nodes manually and insert them at the right positions IMHO. A better solution might be using a simple XSLT transform to merge the documents.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this, aren't there any other API's in XERCES to do this???
Can you please suggest me some site to practically get started using XSLT m new to it..

Comment: I didn't know the `importNode()` method in XERCES, nevertheless really 'merging' two XML documents in general might be more complicated as you cover for your particular use case. If you're still interested in an XSLT solution you can find some sample here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipcombxslt. There are loads of tutorials and references for XSLT in the web, if you want to work with XML professionally, you definitiely should know XSLT.

Comment: Hey, thanks i will surely try for XSLT. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey i found a simple solution:

```
XMLCh * file1= XMLString::transcode("file1");
XMLCh * lists = XMLString::transcode("lists");

DOMNodeList* parNodeList1 = defDoc1->getElementsByTagName(lists);
DOMNodeList* parNodeList2 = defDoc2->getElementsByTagName(root);

DOMNode *defNode1 = parNodeList1->item(0);
DOMNode *defNode2 = parNodeList2->item(0);

temp = defDoc2->importNode(defNode1, true);
defNode2->appendChild(temp);
```

Now you can write the defDoc2, as it is a merger of two files.